# c++ preprocessor directive function

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define func(x) (x*x)-x
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
int i = 3;
cout << func(i+2) << endl;
}
```

Why does func(i+2) return 10? Shouldn't it return func(5) = (5*5) - 5 = 20?

Comment: Always bracket every parameter in macro expansion. And don't use macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression `i+2` is lexically inserted into the placeholders `x` of your macro.
So `func(i+2)` is translated into `(i+2*i+2)-i+2`; with `i==3`, this is `(3 + 2*3 + 2) - 3 + 2` and yields `10`.

In macros, always use `(...)` when using the macro arguments, i.e. write

```
#define func(x) ((x)*(x))-(x)
```

instead.

And, as Neil pointed out, avoid using macros; use functions instead. Functions are less error prone, can be debugged, and usually do not have any negative performance impact:

```
int func(int x) { return x*x - x; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Macros do a simple text substitution .

So

```
func(i+2) -> (i+2*i+2)-i+2 = (3+2*3+2)-3+2 = 3 + 6 + 2 - 3 + 2 = 10
```

Perhaps what you want is

```
#define func(x) ((x) * (x)) - (x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessing turns

```
cout << func(i+2) << endl;
```

into

```
cout << (i+2*i+2)-i+2 << endl;
```

This is then parsed as

```
cout << (i + (2*i) + 2) - i + 2 << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

`func` is not a function, it is a macro.

`func(i+2)` expands to `(i+2*i+2)-i+2`.  The binary `*` operator has a higher precedence than the binary `+` operator, so it gets evaluated as `(i + (2*i) + 2) - i + 2)`.  Given `i = 3`, that gives `(3 + (2*3) + 2) - 3 + 2`, which evaluates to 10.

This is why you should avoid using function-like macros whenever possible, and should always take precautions to prevent things like improper grouping or multiple evaluations of parameters when you do have to use them.

Answer (score 1):

because the macro functio is extracted as follows:

```
(i + 2 * i + 2 ) - i + 2
```

if you calculate this for `i = 3`, it is `10`.

macro functions is not real functions, they  just replace text for you.

so,

`cout << func(i+2) << endl;`

is replaced with:

`cout <<  (i + 2 * i + 2 ) - i + 2 << endl;`